# How to set an ItemsSouce purely from XAMl without data binding?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, itemssource

I know how to data bind. But i know ive done this before where i define an array of strings or ints within Xaml. Note that im referring to Silverlight xaml.

Is it something like this?

ItemsSource="10 20 30"
ItemsSource="10, 20, 30"
ItemsSource="{10 20 30}"
ItemsSource="{{10} {20} {30}}"

Note that none of the these actually work.
The first one, for instance, places each character as a separate item in the list or combobox... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ItemsSource`.  `ItemsSource` is specifically for binding to a collection.  Controls that have an `ItemsSource` property typically have an `Items` property.  Try setting it like this

```
<Control>
    <Control.Items>
        10
        20
        30
    </Control.Items>
</Control>
```

Note that each item is on it's own line.  Also, I can't tell you the syntax off of the top of my head, but I would try to create the collection as a Resource rather than declaring it in the control.  This will make it easier to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to new up actual objects (e.g. Strings) and add it to the ItemsControl.
Make sure to import the `System` namespace for that:

```
...
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
```

Then simply create and add the items:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.Items>
    <system:String>10</system:String>
    <system:String>20</system:String>
    <system:String>30</system:String>
  </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```